# How can I change Angular2 route query parameters without navigating to the route?

Tags: angular2-routing

I have an angular2 page shows a list of items.  I restrict the list initially by using the route parameters so my URL is something like:

> http://localhost:54675/#/listing?filter={"Country":[6, 7]}

This will show items in the country with an ID of 6 or 7.

Then the users adds a third country (let's say 8) and I make a service call which updates the list.  Since the list items are bound to an observable the list then updates on the screen.

This is exactly the behavior I want.  But if the user bookmarks this page they only get the original route parameters and not the filtered results.

To fix this, I use:

```
this._router.navigate(['listing', { filter: newfilter }]);
```

This reloads the page with this route:

> http://localhost:54675/#/listing?filter={"Country":[6,7,8]}

This keeps everything in sync and bookmarks work.  However, there is a full page refresh.  Other items load again - not just the filtered results.  I also like the visual results better when it's just a single service call.

I need a way to change the route parameters without reloading the page.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 23):

You can use the [Router](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#createUrlTree) only to create the URL and then use the [Location](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#go) to change the URL without navigating.

Something like this:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

// Generate the URL:
let url = this.router.createUrlTree(['listing', { filter: newfilter }]).toString();

// Change the URL without navigate:
this.location.go(url);
```

Comment: A very elegant and clean solution! I wanted to add an ID to my route and it worked :) I used the ```this.location.replaceState``` so that when clicking to return to the previous page it would work as expected instead of going back to the same route without the ID.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who still didn't find a proper solution, try this:

```
this._router.navigate([], { 
 relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
 queryParams: {
   filter: newfilter
 },
 queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
});
```

When navigating to the same route, the site doesn't reload!